Ansible task is being skipped and when condition is true
For Some Reason when this task is reached and is_nginx is true it skips it, i've also changed it to a block and put import_tasks inside the block instead of include and it has all the items but just skips them all
It's boggling my mind as i have similar includes with when statements else where and it works fine
There are no other errors so i'm ruling out the vars: block having any issues
Does anyone have any idea what is causing this issue?
Ansible Version
ansible [core 2.14.11]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.11.9 (main, Apr 17 2024, 00:00:00) [GCC 13.2.1 20240316 (Red Hat 13.2.1-7)] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.3
  libyaml = True

Here's the Code with the other tasks removed except one other include tasks which does work, and i've tried changing the non working task to also be an include_tasks under a block like the working one to no avail
i've also added an explicit |bool filter and it doesnt work either
 - block:
    - block:
        - include_tasks: '../user/create_linux_user.yaml'
      vars:
        user_name: '{{ owner_name }}'
        user_group: '{{ group_name }}'
        user_groups: "{{ ((container.groups | default([])) + [ docker_group ]) | interpret_values(vars) }}"
        user_create_home: false
        user_allow_login: false
        group_users: "{{ admin_users }}"
      when: not ansible_check_mode

    - debug:
        var: is_nginx

    - name: '{{ current_job }}: Import NGiNX Config Tasks'
      include_tasks: '{{ common_task_dir }}/nginx/prepare_configs.yaml'
      vars:
        current_job: '{{ current_job }} - NGiNX Setup'
        lscr_config: "{{ docker_image.split('/')[0] == 'lscr.io' }}"
        log_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/log(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"
        sites_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/config/nginx/site-confs(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"
        httpd_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/etc/nginx/http.d(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"
        common_config_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/etc/nginx/common(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"
        html_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/usr/share/nginx/html(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"

        upstream: '{{ docker_container.upstream }}'
        sites: '{{ docker_container.sites }}'
        nginx_user: '{{ owner_name }}'
        nginx_group: '{{ group_name }}'
      when: is_nginx|bool

  vars:
    container_final_name: "{{ sane_container_name ~ name_appender | lower }}"
    docker_image: "{{ container.image }}"
    container_name: "{{ sane_container_name }}"
    environment_variables: "{{ (container.environment | default({})) | combine(docker_environment.common.environment | default({})) }}"

    is_nginx: "{{ docker_image.split(':')[0].split('/')|last|lower == 'nginx' }}"

    assign_user: "{{ (docker_image is not match('^lscr\\.io')) }}"

    sane_container_name: "{{ container.name | lower | trim | regex_replace('[^a-z0-9]', '-') | regex_replace('(^[0-9-]+|-+$)', '') }}"

    container_hostname: "{{ container.hostname | default(container_name) | lower | trim | regex_replace('[^a-z0-9]', '-') | regex_replace('(^[0-9-]+|-+$)', '') }}"
    owner_name: "{{ container.owner | default(docker_environment.common.owner | default(container_name)) ~ name_appender }}"
    group_name: "{{ (container.group | default(container_name)) ~ name_appender }}"
    docker_group: "{{ (docker_environment.group | default('docker')) ~ name_appender }}"

    container_group_base_dir: "{{ environment_base_dir }}/{{ container.group | lower }}/{{ container_name }}"
    container_base_dir: "{{ environment_base_dir }}/{{ container.group | lower }}/{{ container_name }}"
    
    container_networks: "{{ docker_environment.common.networks | default({}) | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'in', container.networks | default([])) | map('combine', {'name': item.key}) | list }}"

    filtered_ports: "{{ container.ports | default([]) | filter_ports(port_prepender) }}"

    volumes:  "{{ 'volumes' | get_volumes(container, docker_environment.common) | sanitize_volumes(docker_environment.containers, docker_environment.volumes, environment_base_dir, container_base_dir, false, container_networks) }}"
    volume_files: "{{ 'files' | get_volumes(container, docker_environment.common) | sanitize_volumes(docker_environment.containers, docker_environment.volumes, environment_base_dir, container_base_dir, true, container_networks) }}"

    sane_volume_directories: "{{ (volumes + volume_files) | get_parent_folders(base_storage) | select('match', '^' ~ base_storage ~ '.*|^[^/]') | unique | sort | reject('match', '^(' ~ base_storage ~ '|' ~ container_base_dir ~ '|' ~ environment_base_dir ~ '|' ~ container_group_base_dir ~ '|' ~ ')/?$') | list }}"

Here's the Import Variant
    - block:
        - name: '{{ current_job }}: Import NGiNX Config Tasks'
          import_tasks: '{{ common_task_dir }}/nginx/prepare_configs.yaml'
      vars:
        current_job: '{{ current_job }} - NGiNX Setup'
        lscr_config: "{{ docker_image.split('/')[0] == 'lscr.io' }}"
        log_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/log(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"
        sites_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/config/nginx/site-confs(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"
        httpd_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/etc/nginx/http.d(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"
        common_config_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/etc/nginx/common(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"
        html_folder: "{{ container_base_dir }}/{{ volumes | select('match', ':/usr/share/nginx/html(:|$)') | first | split(':')[0] }}"

        upstream: '{{ docker_container.upstream }}'
        sites: '{{ docker_container.sites }}'
        nginx_user: '{{ owner_name }}'
        nginx_group: '{{ group_name }}'
      when: is_nginx|bool

Here's the Console Output For the Include Version

TASK [smarthome : debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "is_nginx": true
}

TASK [smarthome : {{ current_job }}: Import NGiNX Config Tasks] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]


Here's the Console Output For the Import Version
TASK [smarthome : debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "is_nginx": true
}

TASK [smarthome : {{ current_job }}: Ensure Site HTML Directory Exists] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [smarthome : {{ current_job }}: Ensure Site WWW Directory Exists] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [smarthome : {{ current_job }}: Ensure Site Static Directory Exists] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [smarthome : {{ current_job }}: Ensure Site Error Directory Exists] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [smarthome : {{ current_job }}: Create Upstream Config] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [smarthome : {{ current_job }}: Create Site Config] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [smarthome : {{ current_job }}: Create Reverse Proxy Config] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

All the other on the same level are working correctly
Every task in the includes has it's own when but to rule out the issue of it being all the whens being false on those tasks i added a debug task that just output test and it skipped that too
To Answer the Questions Below
The Debug Task is Directly before the Include Task, both are on the same level within a block element, and i've included the debug task too above

are these outputs concurrent? I.E there is no other task running between them that might have a side effect setting the is_nginx var to false?

Also is the debug being run at the same level as the  include tasks. Ansible hs i think 20 different variable scopes, wouldnt be the first I have seen a var checked in one scope but when used later its using a different scope

It would be worth showing your debug task, and so a [mre].

@ChrisDoyle i've updated with that info

@β.εηοιτ.βε i've added the debug task and another task on the same level that is also working

The Issue appears to be with the vars: block
am attempting to find the culprit, it's not the current_job even though that is having it's own issue it appears

The issue appears to have been these variables under the vars:
upstream: '{{ docker_container.upstream }}'
sites: '{{ docker_container.sites }}'

I'd have expected an error, but did not get one.
docker_container.sites did not exist, nor did upstream i had used the wrong dict name and i had also erroneously made it an explicit string by use of the ''
I've fixed that and now it's no longer skipping.
